# $push not inserting array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, push

I have this document in mongo:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("509356edf275130917000000"),
  0 => 
  array (
    'id1' => '1000',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'book' => 
    array (
      'id2' => '0',
      'name' => 'Example',
    ),
  ),
)
```

and i want to add a book to "book" array:

```
$coll->update(array(array("id1"=>'1000'),
     '$push'=>array('book'=>array(
        "id2"=>"1",
        "name" =>'War and peace'))));
```

but nothing happens, anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you are talking about mongo then show the objects in JSON format dude...or specify your client language as a tag

Comment: Possible duplicate, please take a look at this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645961/mongodb-updating-elements

Answer (score 0):

`book` is single array. You can't update.

Update records based on a given criteria

```
$collection->update($criteria, $newdata);
```

Example:

```
[
  '_id'     => new MongoId("509356edf275130917000000"),
  'ids'     => [1, 2, 3],
  'books'   => ['Book1', 'Book2']
]
```

---

```
$data = ['books' => 'Book3'];

$collection->update(

    // Criteria 
    ["_id"   => new MongoId("509356edf275130917000000")],

    // New Object 
    ['$push' => $data]
);
```

Comment: I did the following:
$collection->save(array(
 'ids'=>array('1','2','3'),
 'books'=>array('book1','book2')
  ));
and update:  
$data = array('books' => 'book3');
$collection->update(array(
    "_id"   => new MongoId("5093af6af27513c318000001"),
    '$push' => $data
));
but nothing happens. Help me!!

Comment: change collection format.. Tell me more information about fields in your collection. I will help you